# Create a login in for a android application

Tags: android, mysql, database, rest, soap

I am trying to create a login in for my android application. The login would connect to a mysql database. I have no clear idea how to do this because you can't run php on android but I have heard people say to have webservice that is written in php to have it connect with your android application.

Can some one help and show me a path. I heard of REST / SOAP but don't know how either on of them work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check this tutorial explained about login and registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many different ways and different tutorials, here's one or just google android httpClient.

[How-to: Android as a RESTful Client](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/)

and here are some examples on how to setup php and mysql:

[PHP and MySql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

[PHP/MySQL Tutorial](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)

Just take what you learn from those 3 tutorials and put them altogether. If you still don't understand after working through these, you will at least be in a better position to ask specific questions.